# Excel stopped refreshing Olap cubes

Tags: ssis, ssas, cube

since yesterday I have a problem with OLAP Cubes.
They do process successfull and I can browse them in SSMS without any problem but normal users can't refresh the data via Excel.
Me as Admin I can refresh all excels without any problem and my collegue with the same privileges was able to do it only with 1 of 5 excels.
Any help here? After restarting of our server some people were able to refresh it yesterday but today this trick didnt work for us.

```
Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=My_Cube;Data Source=My_Server;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Update Isolation Level=2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was new Excel update v2109. After downgrade to v2108 it's ok.